DeviceDisplay.MainDisplay.Density property returns 0 when embed MaUI button into WinUI native
I have embedded the MAUI button element into WinUI native, and I am trying to obtain the DeviceDisplay.MainDisplay.Density property at Loaded and clicked event of the button and it returns 0 value.
I have used the sample provide in below GitHub link,
https://github.com/dotnet/maui-samples/tree/main/8.0/PlatformIntegration/NativeEmbeddingDemo
When I loaded on the button, I have to get exact DeviceDisplay.MainDisplay.Density property value.
